# Packer failed when executed on Gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, packer

I have a packer file to deploy Centos 7 using vSphere-Iso builder that works Ok when executed directly on a linux server but when I try to run the same packer file using a gitlab-runner it fails as it does not wait until the OS is installed. It fails after waiting for 1 minute but if I run the packer command with -on-error=run-cleanup-provisioner the OS install finish succesuflly so clear the issue is that packer is just not waiting.

```
2021/07/20 12:02:40 packer.io plugin: [INFO] Waiting for IP, up to total timeout: 30m0s, settle timeout: 5m0s
==> vsphere-iso.autogenerated_1: Waiting for IP...
==> vsphere-iso.autogenerated_1: Clear boot order...
==> vsphere-iso.autogenerated_1: Power off VM...
==> vsphere-iso.autogenerated_1: Destroying VM...
2021/07/20 12:03:12 [INFO] (telemetry) ending 
==> Wait completed after 1 minute 2 seconds
2021/07/20 12:03:12 machine readable: error-count []string{"1"}
==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
```

My boot command is the following as I do not use DHCP.

```
boot_command    = ["<up><tab> text inst.ks=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/vmware-ks.cfg ip=10.118.12.117::10.118.12.1:255.255.255.0:{{ .Name }}.localhost:ens192:none<enter><wait>"]
```

I have tested using options like ssh_host, ip_wait_address, ip_settle_timeout, ssh_wait_timeout, pause_before_connecting but nothing seems to work.

As I said, the same packer pkr.hcl file works OK if run it manually on a regular linux but not on my gitlab-runner that is a runner installed directly on my Gitlab server (Yes, I know is not the best practice but I only use the runner for this task)

Packer versions 1.7.2 and 1.7.3 tested, gitlab-runner 14.0.0 and 14.0.1 tested.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work by changing the las wait on my boot command for wait5m. This will give the OS enough time to get installed and the VM rebooted.

```
New boot command boot_command    = ["<up><tab> text inst.ks=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/vmware-ks.cfg ip=10.118.12.117::10.118.12.1:255.255.255.0:{{ .Name }}.localhost:ens192:none<enter><wait5m>"]
```

All the other wait options from packer are no longer needed with this boot command.

Doing some test I managed to make it work as well by creating a Firewall drop rule for the VM just after the kickstar file was loaded and removing the FW rules once the OS was installed. Definitelly, packer is just ignoring all the wait machanism native to packer when running on the gitlab-runner

**EDIT**: After having the same issue with my Windows Templates y tested using a different gitlab-runner installed on a different server instead of the one in the same gitlab server and it worked perfectly with my initial contifiguration for both, windows and centos.